# How to check if a symbol is a keyword?

Tags: symbols, keywords

Values typically passed as property keys are typed symbol, eg:

`(type-of :test)` => `symbol`

However `symbol` type also covers `t`, `nil` end `'test`.

Is there a convenient way to check for a colon prefixed symbol?

---

This is a function that does this, but involves converting the symbol to a string which doesn't seem very elegant.

```el
(defun property-symbol-p (sym)
  (and (symbolp sym) (eq ?: (aref (symbol-name sym) 0)))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function `keywordp` does that:

> -- Function: keywordp object
>
> ```
> function returns ‘t’ if OBJECT is a symbol whose name starts with
> ‘:’, interned in the standard obarray, and returns ‘nil’ otherwise.
> ```

It does essentially the same thing that your function does, except that it's in C.